# psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "superadmin"

Tags: postgresql

Хочу зайти в бд с суперюзера с помощью этой команды:

```
psql --username=superadmin books_db
```

Выходит ошибка *в заголовке*. Уже пробовал и с `sudo`, и указывал точно что это суперюзер, но выходит одна и тоже ошибка. Я новичок в psql (опыт работы - 2 месяца), поэтому я не знаю как это исправить.

Linux (Дистрибутив) = Ubuntu

Установлено на виртуалку

---

P.S.
Список всех юзеров:

```
Role name  |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 books_user |                                                            | {}
 postgres   | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 superadmin | Superuser                                                  | {}
```

Comment: А откуда вы взяли логин superadmin ?

Comment: Это суперюзер который уже я создал под логином superadmin ` CREATE USER superadmin LOGIN SUPERUSER PASSWORD '123'` @newman

Comment: @newman, список юзеров указал в описание под постом

Answer (score 0):

Вероятней всего проблема в том что некорректно настроены варианты авторизации для postgresql

В общем-то это довольно таки объемный кусок документации.  Настраивается это в **pg_hba.conf**. Нужно изменить **peer** на **md5**. После внесения изменений нужно перезапустить сервер базы данных.

Если кратко, то **peer authentication** это авторизация по имени пользователя. Т.е. авторизация идет от имени пользователя, под которым был запушен psql.

**password authentication (m5)** - авторизация по имени и паролю

Таким образом вам надо либо создать в системе пользователя superadmin и запускать psql под этим пользователем. Либо, что проще, переключить настройки авторизации на md5 и тогда psql можно запускать под любым пользователем - надо просто указывать логин в параметрах командной строки.

Comment: Спасибо!!Только есть одна проблема,где находится этот файл просто когда я ввожу `vi pg_hba.сonf`,то он просто говорит что этот файл новый и все